# interactive fit with python

Tags: python, events, keypress, interactive

I want to fit a set of data points with a polynomial function (what I normally do with numpy.polyfit), but I want to let the user choose interactively the degree of the polynomial. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(1,10,0.2)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x,y,'o',color='orange',markeredgewidth=0.3,markeredgecolor='k')
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1,1.1)
def press(event):
  #fig.clf()
  fig.canvas.draw_idle()
  sys.stdout.flush()
  deg = int(event.key)
  coeffs = np.polyfit(x,y,deg)
  p = np.poly1d(coeffs)
  rms = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, p(x)))
  fig.text(0.8,1.02, 'rms='+str(round(rms,4)), rotation=0, color='k',transform=ax.transAxes)
  with open('prova.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write('#Coefficients for a n= '+str(deg)+' polynomial fit\n\n')
    for listitem in coeffs:
      filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
  ln = plt.plot(x,p(x),'-',color='green',linewidth=0.8,zorder=0)
  fig.canvas.draw()
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
plt.show()
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
f = open('prova.txt','r')
cfs = loadtxt('prova.txt', usecols=(0),comments='#')
print(cfs)
```

In this way it is effectively possible to fit the points, but the plots following the first one are overplotted. If I drop the '#' for fig.clf() the code updates the fit but cancel the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At start create global variable with `None`

```
  txt = None
  ln = None
```

And inside `press()` you can check if you already assigned `plot` and `text` and `remove()` it.

```
  global txt
  global ln

  if txt:
    txt.remove()
  txt = fig.text(0.8,1.02, 'rms='+str(round(rms,4)), rotation=0, color='k',transform=ax.transAxes)

  if ln:
    ln[0].remove()
  ln = plt.plot(x,p(x),'-',color='green',linewidth=0.8,zorder=0)

  fig.canvas.draw()
```

Or you can set new `data` and `text`

```
global txt
global ln

if txt:
    # replace text
    txt.set_text('rms={}'.format(round(rms,4)))
else:
    # create first time
    txt = fig.text(0.8, 1.02, 'rms={}'.format(round(rms,4)), rotation=0, color='k', transform=ax.transAxes)

if ln:
    # replace data
    ln[0].set_data(x, p(x))
else:              
    # create first time
    ln = plt.plot(x, p(x), '-', color='green', linewidth=0.8, zorder=0)

fig.canvas.draw()
```

---

Full code

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# --- functions ---

def press(event):
    global txt
    global ln


    #fig.clf()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    sys.stdout.flush()

    deg = int(event.key)

    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, deg)
    p = np.poly1d(coeffs)
    rms = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, p(x)))

    with open('prova.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
        filehandle.write('#Coefficients for a n= {} polynomial fit\n\n'.format(deg))
        for listitem in coeffs:
            filehandle.write('{}\n'.format(listitem))

    if txt:
        txt.remove()
    txt = fig.text(0.8, 1.02, 'rms={}'.format(round(rms,4)), rotation=0, color='k', transform=ax.transAxes)

    if ln:
        ln[0].remove()
    ln = plt.plot(x, p(x), '-', color='green', linewidth=0.8, zorder=0)

    #if txt:
    #    txt.set_text('rms={}'.format(round(rms,4)))
    #else:
    #    txt = fig.text(0.8, 1.02, 'rms={}'.format(round(rms,4)), rotation=0, color='k', transform=ax.transAxes)

    #if ln:
    #    ln[0].set_data(x, p(x))
    #else:              
    #    ln = plt.plot(x, p(x), '-', color='green', linewidth=0.8, zorder=0)

    fig.canvas.draw()

# --- main ---

txt = None
ln = None

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(1, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='orange', markeredgewidth=0.3, markeredgecolor='k')

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
plt.show()

#fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
cfs = loadtxt('prova.txt', usecols=0, comments='#')
print(cfs)
```